# Why I don't see all launchctl daemons/agents with "sudo launchctl list"?

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, homebrew, launchd

I wish to see all launchctl daemons/agents and found [How to show all running launchctl daemons/agents?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134817/how-to-show-all-running-launchctl-daemons-agents)

This doesn't work:

```
> sudo launchctl list | grep -v com.apple.
PID     Status  Label
-       0       org.postfix.master
-       0       org.cups.cupsd
-       0       com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool
-       0       com.vix.cron
244     0       org.ntp.ntpd
```

I doubt that I have that less Non-Apple launchctl daemons/agents.

for example I have those installed and running:

```
> brew services list
Name     Status  User Plist
grafana  stopped      
influxdb started fyodor /Users/fyodor/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.influxdb.plist
mysql    started fyodor /Users/fyodor/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
redis    started fyodor /Users/fyodor/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
telegraf started fyodor /Users/fyodor/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.telegraf.plist
```

I don't see them with `sudo launchctl list`. How to get a complete list?

Comment: `sudo launchctl list | grep -v com.apple.` shows the wanted things on my Sierra - however the ones you show are the only ones that I think are Apple supplied. How exactly does HomeBrew run services?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your launchctl command only shows 'system' deameon/agents.  That won't include your homebrew daemons.  By experimenting, I discovered these two ways of running launchctl which will do what you want. For simpliciy I have not added your grep command.

To show system daemons/agents:

```
> sudo launchctl list
```

To show user daemons/agents:

```
> launchctl list
```

I like to use [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) by soma-zone which allows me to control/change the agents and daemons as well as displaying them in 5 distinct lists:

- User Agents
- Global Agents
- Global Daemons
- System Agents
- System Daemons

Comment: I second the recommendation for LaunchControl.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to get all the `system` and your daemons and agents managed by `launchd`:

```
( /usr/bin/sudo launchctl list ; launchctl list )
```

Here is a way to get all but the Apple ones:

```
( /usr/bin/sudo launchctl list ; launchctl list ) |
grep -v 'com.apple.'
```

Note: to avoid to be trapped into using a fake `sudo` command
(for example from a Trojan horse shell script) always use its full path:
`/usr/bin/sudo`.